# Longitudinal k-means sample data

Tags: time-series, k-means, unsupervised-learning

Having finished the Coursera's Machine Learning course, I would like to put the theories into practice.  Thanks in advance on guiding a newbie!

In particular, I am looking forward to some guidance how to:

1. Some sample longitudinal data that would illustrate k-means grouping
2. how to include time dimension into the analysis?  Say if I collected 10 days worth of data, capturing long/lat every 5 minutes, I would expect at hour x every day there is a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of very good references on this matter. Three I can immediately think of are:

1. [Functional clustering and identifying substructures of longitudinal data](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00605.x/pdf) by Chiou and Li (2007)
2. [Clustering for Sparsely Sampled Functional Data](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/research/fclust.ps) by James and Sugar (2003) and
3. [Distance-based clustering of sparsely observed stochastic processes](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoas/1223908052) by Peng and Mueller (2008)

For your particular problem, I would argue (in very short) that instead of doing the $k$-means on the data matrix themselves you calculate the principal components of your data (clearly you do this after smoothing and interpolating your data on a common grid). You would then perform the $k$-means clustering on the principal components' scores. This two-step approach will almost certainly allow you to visualize your data clustering more effectively.

Other approaches (mostly on non-parametric clustering) also exist but I think they are an overkill at this point. Jacques and Preda (2013) have recently provided an excellent survey on the matter: [Functional data clustering: a survey](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/77/10/30/PDF/RR-8198.pdf) (I tried to link to author-provided reprints where possible).

Comment: I think that, since the data set could also be considered as _time series_, _dynamic time warping (DTW)_ approach is applicable as well: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131284/31372.

Answer (score 0):

1. Google's My Track android app allows output of long/lat.
   However, I wrote my own client to capture the data every 5 minutes.
2. Time dimension - depending on how you want to do it...  I "normalize" the data upfront to do every hour, so the grouping makes more sense.  For example

2

```
37.88    -122.22    11
37.88    -122.22    11
37.88    -122.22    11
37.88    -122.22    11
37.33    -122.50    12
37.33    -122.51    12
37.33    -122.52    12
```

The k-means algorithm, if implemented properly, can handle a matrix.  Using the coursera's machine learning exercise #8, I modified it to handle/visualize 3 dimensional data.  Not too bad.

I don't think more than 3 dimensions can be visualized, though a vectorized implementation will still work.

Cheers,
Simon