# Classification on variable-length time series

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, classification

I have a series of transactions like the following:

- [0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
- [1, 0, 0]
- [3, 3, 1, 1]

I would like to classify each transaction as being part of one of two categories: class A or class B, the issue is that a transaction can have any length from 2 to 150 in my case. What is the best approach for classifying similar variable size time series?

Comment: Do you have more labelled examples ? You might try adding summary values as a separate feature vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) distance measure, which can tell distance between different length time series. This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering) has some nice answers about how to do that.

However it would be instructive to construct certain summary statistics for the series and do the clustering on them.

Comment: Thank you, I applied an algorithm for the compression of the time series and applied DTW with KNN, it's working like a charm. I tested DTW before posting here but wasn't getting good results, you gave me the input to adapt the time series and retry with DTW.