# Evaluating time series clustering through EM/GMM

Tags: time-series, clustering, expectation-maximization

I perform clustering of time series into *k=[2,N]* number of clusters by using either *DTW+kmedoids* or *DTW+single linkage+hierarchical clustering (HC*), as advised in a previous post:  [Dynamic Time Warping Clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering)

Regarding the evaluation of optimum number of clusters, I want to use expectation–maximization (EM) Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) and determine the k that maximizes the log-likelihood for each approach.

My questions are:

- What should be the input dataset in EM/GMM? The DTW similarity distance
  or the raw dataset?
- Can the initializations in EM/GMM be the clusters
  centers of either the kmedoids or randomly selected seeds from the HC
  clusters?
- Should I run k-fold cross-validation of the input dataset with the EM/GMM and return the average log-likelihood value?

Comment: In fact..based on [this paper](http://DOI:%20http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSG.2015.2409786) you can cluster time series with GMM/EM. I am working on how to implement with the well-known scikit-learn tools however. For an evaluation of hte optimal number of clusters, BIC/AIC are what you want to observe. These are also in the library for convenience. The [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html) contains a great summary of how to use GMM/EM on certain data but not time series unfortunately. I'd like to hear of your updates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian Mixture Modeling assumes ypur input data are coordinates in $R^d$ and contain Gaussian-shaped clusters. I don't think you can use this on time series.
Also, GMM is a clustering approach on its own, and I don't see how you could use that to evaluate other clusterings.

Comment: There was some research on energy data for outliers detection with time-series, which they used EM/GMM in this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/8/11/12337) in cycled after applying z-score. However, I tried to re-implement it on similar energy data unsuccessfully. They amid to refill the gaps by this approach.