# Which clustering techniques can be used with Dynamic Time Warping (other than Hierarchical clustering)?

Tags: r, clustering

I have time series of cars' speed (speed observed over time for 50 different drivers driving the same car). I want to find the groups of "similar" driving styles based on these speeds. Therefore, I first apply DTW to compute a dissimilarity matrix between each pair of car speeds. And then use Hierarchical clustering using this matrix.

My question is: Are there any other clustering algorithms that I could use for this purpose? I have studied different algos. that were mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering), but the examples I find use non-time series data. Please direct me to any relevant resource.

You can see some sample data in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945769/how-to-apply-dtw-algorithm-on-multiple-time-series-in-r). I use R.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty.

Almost all except k-means and GMM can be used with distances such as DTW.

But many will "require" more than 50 samples to yield good results. With such tiny data, I would go with HAC.

Comment: Could you please name a few?

Comment: DBSCAN, AP, SC, canopy, ... but again, they work much better if you have enough samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TADPOLE [a]

You CAN you k-means. The convergence in not guaranteed, but in practice it works.

However, I agree that with a small data-set, HAC makes sense

[a] Accelerating Dynamic Time Warping Clustering with a Novel Admissible Pruning Strategy
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Speeded%20Clustering%20Paper%20Camera%20Ready.pdf