# Searching for the correct approach

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I'm writing my Bachelor Thesis within the field of neural networks and I need some preparation of the data I'm using. 
Do you have an idea how I am able to identify the four levels in this graph via machine learning? Especially changing points are of importance for me. In this case it would be the x-values roundabout 2700, 3700 and 4700. 
I already thought of Clustering, but since I'm interested of the different levels, this does not quite work out. 
 [image: Graph of the values to be sorted]

Thankyou, 
Lukas

Comment: What is the dimension of your x-axis? time?

Comment: @nbro The cluster methods I used, did not work. For example k-means.. Do you have a cluster method in mind, that could work?

Comment: @peteR  It's measured data over a period of one hour.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "change point detection" and "change in mean" and you will find various classic textbooks and surveys on this.

> Basseville, M. (1988). Detecting changes in signals and systems-A survey. Automatica, 24(3), 309-326.
>
> Basseville, Michèle, and Igor V. Nikiforov. Detection of abrupt changes: theory and application. Vol. 104. Englewood Cliffs: Prentice Hall, 1993.
>
> Sen, Ashish, and Muni S. Srivastava. "On tests for detecting change in mean." The Annals of statistics (1975): 98-108.